# Get the search results with the found words highlighted

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have this query:

```
SELECT body FROM posts WHERE body LIKE (%man%)
```

The resulting array will contain the whole 'body' field values. How i can retrieve the results with the word "man" (or whatever MySQL decided it's like "man" ) highlighted (put into an HTML tag for example). Or at least get a list of these words.

Notice that the found words can be "mankind" or "manual", So i can't just use str_replace with the word "man" on the found results.

Comment: Why can't you use str replace? You want whole words highlighted rather then fragments?

Comment: No, i want the fragments too.

Comment: str replace should work just fine then.

Answer (score -1):

Where's your table?

`SELECT posts FROM your_posts_table WHERE body LIKE '%man%'`

You can then echo the returned array with any HTML styling you prefer.